# Using regex to extract a double digit number from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I want to extract the "73" from this string:

```
wiring_details_1-6-73
```

The numbers 1, 6 and 73 are all vars so I need it to be value independant, I found [this website](http://www.txt2re.com/index-javascript.php3?s=wiring_details_1-6-73&5) which generated this regex:

```
.*?\\d+.*?\\d+.*?(\\d+)
```

But that seems a bit overkill and complicated, what is the cleanest method to extract the "73"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var string = "wiring_details_1-6-73"
var chunks = string.split("-");
alert(chunks[chunks.length-1]) //73
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/eawBT/

Comment: Perfect just what I was after!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `/\d{1,2}$/`

```
var str = "wiring_details_1-6-73";

var result = str.match(/\d{1,2}$/);
```

this returns an array with the matched number as string and you can access the value as `result[0]`.